# Cannot select Hosting after firebase init command

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have a react project which I'd like to deploy to Firebase Hosting (after a run build).
After installing the global firebase tools ("npm i -g firebase-tools") and logged ("firebase login") in successfully, I ran the "firebase init" command and I get to the step where I can select the Firebase CLI features (please see the following image attached):

[image]

Now, when I'm clicking the up & down arrows on my keyboard the selector skips the second, forth and sixth option. In the next picture I clicked one arrow down on my keyboard and got straight to the functions feature instead of firestore.

[image]

**To be clear, all I want to select is the Hosting feature**. I'll be glad to have your help!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Logout and try to login with firebase login --reauth, it may fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help buddy, unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, it turns out you can init a specific feature, without selecting a feature with the arrow keys.

I managed to solve it just by running a '**firebase init hosting**' command (you can use it for all other features as well).

I hope it'll help those who will face this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Space</kbd> key to select the correct option, then press enter to confirm.

Comment: open cmd terminal, in any case the bash terminal have problem